# Play framework Enumerator.outputStream, what if an exception is thrown

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm testing the following code in play framework 2.4:

```
def error = Action {
  val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>
    // some operations that...
    throw new Exception()
  }
  Ok.stream(enumerator >>> Enumerator.eof).withHeaders(
    CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/plain"
  )
}
```

When an exception is thrown in the function passed to `outputStream`, the enumerator passed into `Ok.stream` hangs forever.
How should I fix this?

Comment: BTW: I've found this pattern here http://greweb.me/2012/11/play-framework-enumerator-outputstream/ (quite old actually)

Comment: Make sure the stream gets closed when an exception is thrown?

Comment: @m-z `val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>
     try {
       throw new Exception()
     } finally {
       os.close()
     }
    }
` didn't work, still hangs.